# How to find a file on iPad?

Tags: iphone, filesystems, fileinfo

I am supposed to have downloaded a file on the iPad simulator, using an appication.

How can I check that this file is present on the iPad simulator file system ?

Is there some file manager that I can use to check the existence of the file and possibly its contents?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the simulator at

> /Username/Library/Application
>   Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/

where "4.2" is the SDK version. 
Under that folder you find all applications in cryptical subfolders. One of them is yours.
In there you'lss find "Documents" which is your app's personal folder.

Comment: Your comment helped me find the file I was looking for. But strangely enough I did not find it in the place you mentioned. The file was under the root directory of my computer file system, in other words under /. How is this possible ? I did some test afterward, erasing the file and executing the application inside the iPad simulator again. And I could see the file again under the root directory.

Comment: The simulator can access your whole harddrive. Your code will fail on a real iOS device. The root on your disk is "/" but for your application it should be the app's document folder which is NSDocumentDirectory (this is unique for each app!). You are probably saving to "/myfile.txt" instead of "[App's Document root]/myfile.txt".

Comment: /* NSString * theFolder = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@""];
 NSString * theFileName = [theFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"localFile.txt"];*/


 NSString * theFolder = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:NSDocumentDirectory];
 NSString * theFileName = [theFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"localFile.txt"];

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. I see, you must be right.

This is the code I used to set my locale file :

 NSString * theFolder = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@""];
 NSString * theFileName = [theFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"localFile.txt"];

What should it be ?

I tried this :
 NSString * theFolder = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:NSDocumentDirectory];
 NSString * theFileName = [theFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"localFile.txt"];

But I can see a warning message in my XCode telling me it must not be quite right.

Comment: To get the document's folder (that is what you want, not the HOME directory):

NSString *homeDir = NSHomeDirectory();
NSArray *arrayPaths = 
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
        NSDocumentDirectory,
        NSUserDomainMask,
        YES);

NSString *docDir = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];

The home directory is your app's root dir which changes everytime you reinstall the application. "Documents" is the place for your app's data which is located below home.

Answer (score 1):

Use these methods, you can verify a file is present in the documents directory.  I've not tested this exact example but it should work.

Example:

```
NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePathInDocuments:@"MyFile.txt"];
if([self fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    NSLog(@"The file exits at %@", filePath);
} else {
    NSLog(@"The doesn't exist at %@", filePath);
}
```

Code:

```
- (NSString *)dataFilePathInDocuments:(NSString*)aFilename {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];
}

- (BOOL) fileExistsAtPath:(NSString*)aFilepath {
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    return [fm fileExistsAtPath:aFilepath];
}
```